# find length of opposite when you only have incomplete length of adjacent

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is probably a really stupid question, but say you have the following:

[image]

How do you find the length of `x` given that we only have an incomplete length of  the adjacent here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y$ be the side opposite the right angle. We have $y=360$ because the angle opposite to side of $360$ is also $35$ degrees: $180°-(180°-70°)-35°$. Then $x=y \sin 70°\approx 338.3$

Comment: Sorry, could you expand on this a bit more? I'm not really following. What do you mean "the angle opposite to side of 360 is also 35 degrees: 180°−(180°−70°)−35° ." ? What is that formula and how do you get from that to why we're using sin?

Comment: @AdjunctProfessorFalcon: Look at the triangle that has known side $360$. The angle next to $70$ degree angle is $180°-70°=110°$. The remaining angle (using sum of angles in a triangle is $180°-110°-35°=35°$. Thus, the triangle is isosceles and $y=360$

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also use a system of equations, as an alternative way. Let $a$ equal the unknown segment of the adjacent side. Write an equation relating the opposite and adjacent sides in both the small right triangle and the large right triangle.
$$\begin{cases}
\tan 35\unicode{xb0} = \frac{x}{360+a} \implies (360+a)\tan 35\unicode{xb0} = x
\\
\\
\tan 70\unicode{xb0} = \frac{x}{a} \implies a\tan 70\unicode{xb0} = x
\end{cases}
$$

Now, set $x = x$.

$$(360+a)\tan 35\unicode{xb0} = a\tan 70\unicode{xb0}$$

$$360\tan 35\unicode{xb0}+a\tan 35\unicode{xb0} = a\tan 70\unicode{xb0}$$

$$a\tan 70\unicode{xb0}-a\tan 35\unicode{xb0} = 360\tan 35\unicode{xb0}$$

$$a(\tan 70\unicode{xb0}-\tan 35\unicode{xb0}) = 360\tan 35\unicode{xb0} \implies a = \frac{360\tan 35\unicode{xb0}}{\tan 70\unicode{xb0}-\tan 35\unicode{xb0}} \approx 123.12725$$

Now, plug in the value of $a$ in either of the two equations to get $x$.

$$a\tan 70\unicode{xb0} = x \implies x = \frac{360\tan 35\unicode{xb0}\tan 70\unicode{xb0}}{\tan 70\unicode{xb0}-\tan 35\unicode{xb0}} \approx 338.28934$$